# Use custom styles in Swagger UI for your html tags

Tags: css, swagger-ui

I can add custom html info in (down below C# samples)

```
c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Description ="... here ..."
```

html tags are supported here, but styles are not.
To use custom style (colored span, link with not default blue color, etc.) I have to add custom css swagger.css (can change name and put in deeper folder structure)
in project root under /wwwwroot/swagger.css, make it embedded resource and inject that custom css in `Configure` method

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
  options.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1"); 
  options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
  options.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.List);
  options.InjectStylesheet("/swagger.css");  // <<< inject css
});
```

The caveat is that traditional css is not supported, for example,

```
//swagger.css
.rcolor {color:red !important;}

//html in OpenApiInfo/Description
<a class='rcolor' href='...'>this should be red link</a>
```

does not change color of the link.

To apply colors swagger ui tag navigation should be used: apply unique html tag pattern to your element - instead of simple `<a>...</a>` put `<a><span>...</span></a>` for example
and change css (.swagger-ui, .info are predefined styles which comes with swagger - you can see it in the browser dev tools/inspect and our OpenApiInfo/Description section is right inside this style .info) to

```
.info a span {
    color: red !important;
}

.info span a {
    color: green !important;
}
```

and now this

```
"<pre>colored samples <span><a id='111'>span / a</a></span> , <a id='111'><span>a / span</span></a> "
```

will look like

[image]

Note, that `.info a span` was not a good idea since it also colored `http://localhost/./swagger/v1/swagger.json` link - indeed in the browser inspector you can see that it is `<a>...<span>...`. But you can easily fix it by apply your unique html tag nesting.

Does anybody have better solution for custom styles in swagger ui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger UI ignores HTML `style`, `class`, and `data-*` attributes in Markdown content [for security reasons](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4155#issuecomment-360648261). There's the [`useUnsafeMarkdown`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#user-content-useunsafemarkdown) configuration option to disable this behavior, but it's deprecated and you should not rely on it.

The solution you came up with looks like a viable workaround for inline color styling.